# Category-theoretic characterization of $L$

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, constructibility

Does there exist a characterization of Goedel's constructible universe $L$ in purely category-theoretic terms, or is constructibility an 'artifact' of material set theory?  If, in fact, constructibility is an 'artifact' of material set theory, is there a category-theoretic 'analogue' for $L$?

Comment: As far as I know, this is an open problem.

Comment: @MikeShulman:  Has there been any progress made on this 'open problem'?  Has there been any interest by category-theorists in developing such a characterization?

Comment: If, in fact, my question is an open problem, Peter Koepke's work on ordinal turing machines (and the equivalent formulation of $\ast$-recursion on $Ord$ provided by Koepke and Koerwien in their paper, "The Theory of Sets of Ordinals") might provide a basis by which this open problem might be solved.

Comment: I don't know of any significant progress.  I expect people would be interested in such a characterization.

Comment: @MikeShulman:  In his paper, "Ordinals, Computations, and Models of Set Theory", Peter Koepke makes the following observation in Section 6 of that paper, titled "Assembling Sets Along Wellfounded Relations":  "In standard set theory a set $x$ can be defined as a _point in a wellfounded relation_:  consider the $\in$-relation on the transitive closure $TC$({$x$}) with distinguished element $x$$\in$$TC$({$x$}).  By the Mostowski Isomorphism Theorem, $x$ is uniquely determined by the pair ($x$, $TC$({$x$})) up to order isomorphism."  Would this be an adequate representation of an

Comment: (cont.) abstract set in standard set theory (presumably $ZF$ or $ZFC$)?

Comment: Yes, of course.  There are lots of ways of representing material sets in structural set theory, see for instance https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set or https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3802 and references cited therein.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following statement from Lawvere's paper, "Cohesive Toposes and Cantor's '*lauter Einsen*' (*Philosophia Mathematicae* (3) Vol. 2 (1994), pp. 5-15):

> It might seem that G$\ddot o$del's $L$ would rest, if anything does, on von Neumann's a priori *$\epsilon$*-chains, but that was refuted twenty years ago by William Mitchell who showed how to construct it from a suitable given *category*, structured only by composition of maps; however, to my knowledge this has not been pursued since.

Though it might not be 'kosher' to answer a question with a question, why does Mitchell's construction not provide the necessary category-theoretic characterization of $L$ I seek (Mitchell's construction is contained in his papers, "Boolean Topoi and the Theory of Sets" (*Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* 2(1972), 261-274) and "Categories of Boolean Topoi" (*Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* 3 (1973) 193-201))?

Comment: As far as I know, what's involved here is just that membership-based set theory can be interpreted in appropriate categories of sets, either by using the structure $(\text{TC}(\{x\}),\in)$ from your earlier comment or by using the trees obtained by unraveling this structure. Once this is done, you can just translate traditional set theory (including the definition of $L$) into category-theoretic language.

Comment: Technical addendum: The set theory that gets interpreted into the theory of well-pointed topoi with natural-numbers object is a version of Zermelo set theory (so without replacement) with separation only for formulas with all quantifiers bounded (but the bounds can include power sets, so it's not too weak). The development of $L$ in that theory requires a bit of caution.

Comment: As a standard comment: one can strengthen the definition of (well-pointed) elementary topos a little to get analogues of the replacement axiom, and Replacement after doing the above construction. Mike Shulman's paper on the stack semantics does this using the concept of _autology_, though there are other approaches, eg McLarty's.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  Regarding your technical addendum, what should one be looking out for in "developing"  (defining?) $L$ in a well-pointed topos with a natural-numbers object (since you advise "a bit of caution")?  Also, what is the weakest set theory necessary to define and prove the G$\ddot o$del Characterization Theorem (the one that 'characterizes' (?) the $\Delta_0$- formulas in terms of the G$\ddot o$del operations, in particular, the systems mentioned in Mathias' paper,  "The Strength of Mac Lane Set Theory"?

Comment: The caution that I had in mind comes from the fact that the usual construction of $L$ uses transfinite recursion on the ordinals and thus involves replacement. Without replacement, one needs to work with general well-ordered sets rather than von Neumann ordinals, and one needs to formulate the definition of $L$ in a way that doesn't use replacement to justify transfinite recursion.

Comment: On your other question, about the weakest set theory needed for a particular theorem, I don't know enough about extremely weak set theories to give you useful information about that.  Presumably, you don't need any form of power set, so it would be quite different from what topos theory gives you.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  Very helpful, thanks.  If "without replacement, one needs to to work with general well-ordered sets rather than von Neumann ordinals...", would the absence of Replacement in structural set theories such as $ETCS$ or Mac Lane set theory make such set theories 'structural' rather than 'material' (probably not, since Replacement can be expressed in terms of category theory and can be added to $ETCS$ or Mac Lane set theory)?

Comment: As far as I know, the distinction between structural and material set theories is that in material theories each set has some structure "built in". For example, in ZF, a set $X$ comes with not only its members but also their members (because the members of $X$ are themselves sets), and their members, etcIn structural set theories this sort of structure is not built in but must be given explicitly.  So I don't think the presence or absence of replacement really affects the strucural-material distinction. Zermelo set theory is just as material as Zermelo-Fraenkel.